# Adding multiple objective C Framework to make one swift framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

This is a simple questions which I want to ask, I am building an application which uses multiple third party objective C Frameworks and I have made some codes to work with these frameworks now my requirement is to make a Swift Framework which will consist of third party objective C Frameworks and when used in Swift Applications, the components from those third-party frameworks can be easily used.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Shripada how to make a Swift Framework which includes Objective C third party frameworks? like I have three third party obj c frameworks and I have some codes, now after the build the resulting framework should include those third party frameworks as well as my codes